# Get Category name from Products when adding to Shopping Cart

Tags: php, magento-1.8

Using **Magento 1.8v**.

In my customization when customer adding products to **cart**.
Some products qty should not be changeable **(i.e qty is fixed)** and some other products **qty available** to change .

Example :

```
cat1 
  products 
cat2
  subcat
    products
  subcat
    products
cat3
  subcat
     products
```

**For Example:**
 cat1 products allowed for qty change so when adding to shopping cart it will be 1  and remaining category should not allowed so it is stock item value .

Im trying below code in this class `Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` but throwing error

```
$categoryIds=$this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds($productid);
    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)    
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    if ($category->getName() == 'cat1')   
        $minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();  
   else if($category->getName() == 'cat2')                        
         minimumQty=stock_item->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
```

How do i get category name ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
// Get category id by product id.
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        if ($count < 10) {
            $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('eq' => 1));
            foreach($categories as $cat) {
                if(trim($cat) == 'xxx') { // If category_name == 'xxx' 
                    // Do something.
                    break;
                }
            }
            $count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

QuoteItems have `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` a method called `getProductId`.
You might load the Products and consequently it's categories by looping over the QuoteItems.